# need help identifying which set these 3 bags are from

Tags: set-identification

[image: lego help]

I ended up with three lego bags but need help identifying them.
mostly light grey and dark grey with some blue and burgundy.
The bags say 2011 lego on recycle symbol.
There are two clear half spheres  as well as a plastic ring 4580665

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two [black sprocket wheels](http://brickset.com/parts/4582792) and the [transparent dome](http://brickset.com/parts/4624369) from bag 4 suggest that this set is the [Malevolence](http://brickset.com/sets/9515-1/Malevolence), but many easily identifiable parts are missing. However, your set also seems to miss at least a few bags (numbers 2 and 3), so it is highly probable that you have a partial set.

Comment: thanks,could be. I have some random bags but these 3 are all consistent so I assume they go together. the grey and blue and bubble definitely match, if it is the star wars set, would the red ones be on the interior?

Comment: Yes, see the first few pages of the instruction manual: http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/6015581.pdf

Comment: You are welcome :) You can also tick the mark by the answer to indicate that it was useful to you, this will show others that this question already has an answer.